# Help identifying time series model

Tags: time-series, arima

I am trying to fit an arima model to data below. The best model seems to be ARMA(2,2) with the first AR and MA components zero to me. However, it does not quite satisfy me. I am looking for any ideas to lead me to a better model. Data plot, acf, pacf and fitted model results are below

```
  [1]  3.800731572  1.964861846 -0.330186755 -2.074280974  0.045544766  1.414932643
  [7] -1.772733971 -0.269238758  2.201851709 -0.923099841 -2.022964462  1.244593286
 [13]  0.138510229  0.207393784 -1.179208337 -2.600458137  1.597338790  2.672883672
 [19]  0.021512541 -0.239735960 -0.241002298 -2.652076605 -1.006429172  4.069421128
 [25]  1.567593649 -3.809127815 -1.098172055  0.461986823 -0.371368587  2.377791538
 [31] -0.343117083 -1.627939880 -1.495075368  1.089181437  0.559939059 -1.628253076
 [37]  2.110155105  1.016467745 -2.427617328  1.244370318  0.964439525 -1.102202024
 [43]  0.165851643 -0.229573936 -1.624649814  0.295206971  0.068025881 -1.134450650
 [49] -0.028201597  2.503538284  1.114222419 -2.833496083 -0.522543695  0.050113179
 [55]  0.125369098  2.105797843  2.830923699 -4.856194214 -3.273881724  3.279800792
 [61]  2.239616685 -0.908085837  0.139333522 -1.450735818 -0.803266180  2.190218597
 [67]  1.173394051 -1.246471581  1.242838802  0.072678970 -2.275862413 -0.107232220
 [73] -0.536815960 -0.194192692  4.280008694 -0.434172239 -4.423742767 -0.086640065
 [79]  1.953905466  0.980978972  0.718926929 -2.118235181 -3.086168990  3.488865741
 [85]  3.599936662 -3.739336414 -0.543348582  0.301020550 -1.055976766  2.578110734
 [91]  1.595147532 -1.380082733 -1.554146884  1.611852730 -0.024437323 -0.695824440
 [97]  1.212412282 -0.905360495 -1.731530168  0.175207750  2.228134579 -0.249534514
[103]  0.317061339  0.301498249 -2.915450651  0.700227471  4.178040621  0.300634992
[109] -2.775388196 -0.813531442  1.682700373  0.170627572 -0.304814504  0.593898664
[115]  0.705283783  0.247763384 -0.973869829  0.797997103 -0.210376025 -0.664768398
[121]  0.007792289 -0.123965987 -1.053204162  1.317299536  3.605380859 -0.207812137
[127] -2.753767618 -0.953270567  1.302774452  0.475310161  0.439760253 -0.519127147
[133] -2.713290201  0.528059101  1.590144928  0.290186322 -1.140784855 -0.290639801
[139]  0.451966832 -1.829276852  0.616356479  3.382008422 -0.372334534  0.586538986
[145]  1.065393107 -1.045478951 -1.297666091 -0.804821865 -0.894058890  0.945981384
[151]  1.865434286 -2.347928952 -1.145754072  4.593493727 -0.509447663 -1.593344586
[157]  0.161678089 -1.102974728  1.219269299  2.142194154 -2.169974430 -0.847790444
[163]  2.112060982 -1.994966429 -1.549014700  2.163255646 -0.794707401 -0.255578617
[169]  1.691674982 -0.901877878 -0.336901862  2.345808096 -1.869011631  0.415512418
[175]  1.417162468 -0.189171118  0.604161930 -2.354043433 -3.087017949  1.391578651
[181]  1.607888511 -2.601455766  1.653942000  1.040655043 -2.547348811 -0.811884895
[187]  1.291304418  1.346237124  0.646396579 -0.888786433 -1.238057892 -0.801669576
[193]  0.360090751  0.751050406  0.273321234 -0.919838506 -0.791943921  1.771953858
[199] -0.306807634 -1.033265249
```

[image]

[image: acf]
[image]

```
ARIMA(2,0,2) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
      ar1      ar2  ma1      ma2  intercept
        0  -0.3677    0  -0.6407    -0.0044
s.e.    0   0.0767    0   0.0536     0.0222

sigma^2 estimated as 1.366:  log likelihood=-316.07
AIC=638.14   AICc=638.57   BIC=657.93
```

Comment: You say you include fitted model results. Where are they?

Comment: I put them now. Sorry for inconveniance

Comment: Is the "(0,NA,0,NA)" part simply specifying that the first AR and MA components are zero?

Comment: yes,it is the notation in R

Comment: Anybody who doesn't use time series in R is unlikely to guess its meaning, so you must make it explicit what you mean in the question; I'd suggest replacing (0,NA,0,NA) with a sentence explaining that you have set the specific coefficients to zero.

Comment: This isn't the first time series you posted here with 200 observations. What's the link between these series? That may give a hint to those who want to help you.

Comment: There is no relation between the series. Thank you for your interest

Comment: how did you determine if this is the best model ?